# New screen in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How to create a GUI in MATLAB that when clicking the button it changes to a new interface (new screen).

I have a program that generates a certain graphic, i wanted that when i clicked on a button it changed the screen of the GUI to another one with another graphic.

Answer (score 1):

When you save a GUI in MATLAB, there are two files. One is fig file which is a user-designed figure, namely a picture. Another one is a m file which contains the code. There is no relationship between two figures. This is totally different with C# and other languages. So, we consider this m file is an isolated program. To execute it, we run it with following code.

```
run('.\MfileName.m')
```